# Adding updated data using a form to MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

I am new to PHP and appreciate all the help I receive.

OK so I now understand that simply resubmitting a form does not over write any previous data on the database what was ending before resubmitting the for.

I was wondering how I would set it so that the database updates the data that needs updating with the new data.

My form works 100% fine other then a few things I would like to iron out and this is one of them. I have looked around google and everything but I can't make sense of anything that I find as all answers are different and there is not a set answer to my question.

```
if(isset($_POST["signupbtn"])) {
    if ($log_username) {
        /// getting data from submitted form into local variables
        $x = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['xbox']);
        $p  = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['psn']);
        $s = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9]#i', '', $_POST['steam']);
        $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
        // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR GAMER PROFILES
        $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE xbox='$x' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
        $x_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        // -------------------------------------------
        if ($x_check > 0){ 
            echo "Xbox Gamer-Tag already linked to a user on this website";
            exit();
        } else if (is_numeric($x[0])) {
            echo 'Xbox Gamer-Tag cannot begin with a number';
            exit();
        }
        $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE psn='$p' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
        $p_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        // -------------------------------------------
         if ($p_check > 0){ 
            echo "PSN User already linked to a user on this website";
            exit();
        } else if (is_numeric($p[0])) {
            echo 'PSN User cannot begin with a number';
            exit();
        }
        $sqli = "SELECT username FROM player WHERE steam='$s' LIMIT 1";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli); 
        $s_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
         if ($s_check > 0){ 
            echo "Steam account already linked to a user on this website";
            exit();
        } else if (is_numeric($s[0])) {
            echo 'Steam account cannot begin with a number';
            exit();
        } else  { $sqli = "INSERT INTO player (id, username, xbox, psn, steam, ip, created, lastupdated, notecheck)        
                VALUES ('$id','$log_username','$x','$p','$s','$ip',NOW(),NOW(),NOW())"; 
                $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sqli);
                   echo "Gamer Profiles Updated";
                }   

        exit();

            if (!file_exists("p_player/$log_username")) {
                mkdir("p_player/$log_username", 0755);
            } 


     }


}
```

As you can see that is my current php what is working fine except the fact that I can't update information that has been submitted.

Thank you for reading this and I hope someone is able to provide me with the knowledge that is need to preform this task.

Thanks once again for your time it has taken for you to read this post.

Comment: When exactly would you be "updating" the user? When `$s_check` is not empty? When `$p_check` is not empty? At a different time?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you'd need to check whether the data is equal to what you're wanting to update. Using a `WHERE column='data'` and if it's not equal to it, update. Correct? You could also use a query inside a conditional statement to check whether the data going in is the same as an existing one.

Comment: @fred yes if the data is not equal to what is already in the database I would like to delete the current data and then add the new data so someone can update there info when and if needed to

Comment: You won't have to use `DELETE`, updating it will just overwrite what's presently in there, IF it needs to be replaced. You could also make use of the `REPLACE INTO` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not precisely sure "where" in your code you want to perform the actual update since you have several spots where it detects an existing account; however, the overall goal to be achieved can be done with a straightforward `UPDATE` clause.

Let's assume, for instance, you have the user's `id` that you want to update. Your MySQL query would then look like `UPDATE player SET ... WHERE id = ?`. If we want to port that to PHP with the variables you're using, you would use:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
    UPDATE player
    SET xbox = ?, psn = ?, steam = ?, ip = ?, lastupdated = NOW()
    WHERE id = ?
');
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $x, $p, $s, $ip, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The above creates a prepared statement and binds all appropriate variables.

If you *don't* know a user's `id` but you want to update their info when, for instance, they submit a duplicate Steam account (`$s`), you could use something similar to:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('
    UPDATE player
    SET xbox = ?, psn = ?, ip = ?, lastupdated = NOW()
    WHERE steam = ?
');
$stmt->bind_param('ssss', $x, $p, $ip, $s);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

This is also portable for cases for both xbox and psn; however, I would recommend creating actual user-tracking so other users can't inadvertently overwrite a different user's info (if it will be public-facing, that is).

Comment: I will not have a problem with splitting up the forms and making 3 separate forms for 3 separate inputs but I would still get the same problem as the username, ip and dates would not get updated. I am not 100% bothered where the updates take place or whether I need to do 3 to start with as I will be able to changed things about and have a play if I know what I need to add to be able to preform the update in the first place. Thank you for your reply

Comment: I will know the username that is trying to update the profile so I am guessing I will be able to use this instead of using the ID

Comment: @LukeG Correct, it will work the same way with `WHERE username = ?` instead =]

Comment: I am guessing I do not put the ? and would actually put the variable that contains the active users username.

Comment: @LukeG My examples use prepared statements; the `?` is dynamically populated when you would call `$stmt->execute();`. If you want to *not* use prepared statements, I suggest you take a look at [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string) to prevent SQL Injection.

Comment: OK thank you for the feedback. I have not really used any prepared statements yet so that would be another problem. If I am unable to do what I need to do then I will need to look into using prepared statements so I can use your method. Thank you for answering

Answer (score 0):

I took this from one of my scripts, and is basically done like the following:

The `$_POST['query_var'];` would come from your form input, resembling:

```
<input type="text" name="query_var">
```

Then, the SQL part:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
$query= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['query_var']);
$query_check = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `your_table` WHERE `column_to_check` = '". $query ."' "); 

if (mysqli_num_rows($query_check) > 0) 
{ 
echo "Data is the same";
}

else{
// do something else
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. I believe the else is where I would execute the UPDATE function?

Comment: Would this run instead of using INSERT or would I still have to use INSERT if they was entering submitting data for the fist time and if I still need to use INSERT how would I execute that instead of executing the UPDATE function. I told you I was new to it all

Comment: I suggest that you work with a "copy" of a new code file, then try it out in conjunction with what you have. However, it could work by itself, depending if you're just checking the one column at a time. @LukeG

Comment: OK I will see if I can get my head around it all lol. Thanks for answering once again

Comment: once last question before I kill myself with getting it to work. I believe I am not tied down to using query_var as a name for each field am I.

Comment: You're welcome. No, you're not confined to using `query_var`. But when you do change it, make sure you change all instances of the same name. @LukeG Keep me posted.

Comment: I have ran using Update instead. It does add the data to the database the first time running through it but then if I was to re run to update my info then it just echo out success and nothing gets update to the database

Comment: Was this in using the **same** data, as in the original goal? @LukeG

Comment: Sorry the above is redundent it was because I ran my other test after trying however it does come back with these errors after running a 2nd time http://gyazo.com/8a121a2302e83d6d94dbcd2e5684b0d6

Comment: Just to clarify. Yes I ran this instead of running the original submit.

Comment: Did you base yourself on what I put for the DB connection `$con=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");` and `$query= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['query_var']);` @LukeG

Comment: I kept the names the same on the field names just to keep things separate from the other fields

Comment: Ok, I see where it's going wrong. Change (all) where I have `$con` to `$db_conx` @LukeG my `$con` was the DB connection variable I used as an example, since I didn't know what yours was.

Comment: I just seen that all things are called 'xbox' as well. I will sort that out and then give it a run. I will also update to what you have said about $con

Comment: Just do a search for `$con` and replace for `$db_conx` in your editor @LukeG

Comment: I have changed that all now. How ever it is coming back with errors now instead of posting or updating. here is errors http://gyazo.com/4b13efeb67439de223f16f83b6c9e309  AND THIS IS CURRENT CODE http://gyazo.com/2564ac617702f076969a794157394d6f

Comment: Do the other ones work and just the one not working, or are they all not working now? @LukeG

Comment: None are working. It only work the first time as I think it was because they were all name 'xbox' in MySQLi part but not on form. sorry about this

Comment: this is the error I now get after sorting out the other errors http://gyazo.com/3a925148ceaa5c1c10ac277750395d47

Comment: Probably because there is no result found and it doesn't have an escape route to take. You're using too many conditional statements, based on the sams query, in a way. The way I made my answer, is that if one query finds something, then do something. I then needs an `else{ // do something else with THAT query }` type of thing. @LukeG

Comment: It's basically, `if { THIS found, do this }` --- `else { do something else }` I can't rewrite your whole code, I'd have setup a complete database etc. @LukeG

Comment: ok. I am just doing the one input from form and also on MySQLi new code http://gyazo.com/a2fb0df96da16034380c47f884d5f44a

Comment: The `column_to_check` and `your_table` that was just an example. You need to change those to what fits YOUR DB/table, not what I posted. Again, that was just an example. I can't help you anymore than I already have, sorry. This is just taking too much of my time, plus SO stands at closing this question automatically and I have no control over this.

Comment: I really do apologize I seen that after. That was a re-edit I was doing and didn't change it but have now. It brings back the same result I have stated anyway. I appreciate all the help you have gave me so far. I will just start again and see if I can get it to work if not I will just do more searches I guess. Thanks anyways.